# Coloring half of a triangle in CSS

Tags: html, css, triangle

I need to fill the top-half of the triangle with black like in the picture
(*#d3* is the triangle div):

Here's HTML code:

```css
#d1 {
  background: #191919;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#d2 {
  background: #F9E492;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#d3 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 150px solid #4F77FF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>CSSBATTLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">
      <div id="d3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Screenshot-CSS-battle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTI9M.png)

I prefer a simple answer because I'm new to CSS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::after` selector and positioning it absolute, making it's borders bottom radius at 50%.

```css
#d1 {
  background: #191919;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#d2 {
  background: #F9E492;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#d3 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 150px solid #4F77FF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50px;
}

#d3::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 89px solid transparent;
  border-right: 89px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 89px solid #000;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -89px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>CSSBATTLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">
      <div id="d3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

N.B. I used pixel for positioning the triangle but I'll suggest you to use % or any other non-pixels unit

Comment: What is the purpose of an empty content here.

Comment: if you don't set a contenT you won't view the pseudo element

Answer (score 0):

```css
  #d1 {
  background: #191919;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#d2 {
  background: #F9E492;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#d3 {
  height:150px;
  width:300px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50px;
  background:#4F77FF;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
#d4{
    height:100px;
    background:#000000;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>CSSBATTLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">
      <div id="d3">
        <div id="d4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
#d1{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
#d2{
    height:100px;
    background:#000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Triangle top black</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="d1">
    <div id="d2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution and requirement doesn't match

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).